# Passar Dados para outras telas JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controller, view

Galera que mexe com JavaFX, estou precisando muito de ajuda, estou tentando passar dados de um tela para outra só que não consigo.

No meu projeto eu faço login com um usuário buscando no banco de dados. Cada usuário tem um `id`. Eu preciso que, na hora que ele faça o login, eu consiga mandar esse `id` para a tela principal para poder mexer nas demais coisas com esse `id`.

Eu tenho Login.Controller, login.fxml. login.tela, e o tela principal a mesma coisa, seguindo o padrão MVC.

No código abaixo eu faço o login, nessa hora eu queria manda o `id` do usuário para minha tela principal.

```java
public void logar() {

        DAO<Usuarios> dao = new DAO<Usuarios>(Usuarios.class);
        List<Usuarios> users = dao.obterTodos();

        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

            if (txEmail.getText().equals(users.get(i).getEmail()) && txSenha.getText().equals(users.get(i).getSenha())) {
                idUsu = users.get(i).getId();//consigo guardar o id nessa varivel que criei
                Principal p = new Principal();
            
                i = users.size();
                fechar();
                try {
                    p.start(new Stage());
                    
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);alert.setTitle(idUsu.toString());
                    alert.show();//fiz um teste de alerte pra ver se realmente pegava o id na variavel que criei
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu te daria duas alternativas

**1ª**
Torne esses atributos estáticos assim você pode usá-lo em qual parte do código.

**2ª**
No deves criar um método público na classe controlador que recebe esses dados da Tela Inicial(Ou qualquer tela que deseje).